# Improve communication between JFrame and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am working on a small game that needs communication between the main `JFrame` and a `JPanel` called `gamepan`.

the game requires that the user finds a hidden word by clicking on buttons that contains alphabet letters.

My `JFrame` Contains the `gamepan`, `scorepan`,`menus` and other stuff...

my `gamepan` contains my `buttonsArrayListener`, the hidden word and other stuff...

the problem is, when the user finds the hidden word I need to tell my `JFrame` that he did so this later can repaint the `gamepan`, make a new word ....

what I did is : I added a `boolean` in my `gamepan` that tells if my word is found or not and a `MouseListener` to my `gamepan`, so everytime I move the mouse the `JFrame` tests if the word is found or not
then added setters in my `gamepan` that I use from the `JFrame` to initialise things again if the hidden word if found.

I find that this is not verry effective to add a `MouseListener` since I have to mouve the mouse to make the change, and everytime the mouse moves useless treatements are made ...

I want to know if there is a better sollution than adding a `MouseListener` ?? and I want to know also if I did good to add setters to the `gamepan` to set its variables for a new word.

Here is my code

gamepan code

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
private JPanel leftPan = new JPanel();
private JPanel rightPan = new JPanel();
private String[] letters =     {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",};
private JButton Button[] = new JButton[26];

private JLabel label1;
private JLabel label2;
private JLabel label3;
private ActionListener buttonListener;
private JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();

private Word randWord = new Word(); // mot aléatoire
private TreatedWord tWord = new TreatedWord(randWord.getRandWord());// mot  aléatoire traité ( etoiles et tout ça )
private char clickedButton;// lettre tappée
private boolean motTrouvé = false; // pour informer la classe Fenetre si le mot a été retrouvé ou pas on utilise ce boolean avec son getter et setter ( a savoir que cette classe est informée si le mot est trouvé ou pas via l'objet tWord)


private final List<CustomListener> customListener = new LinkedList<>(); //On crée une liste de CustomListener pour en ajouter autant qu'on veut(Via addCustomListener)

public GamePanel(){
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    initGamePan();
    initListeners();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(leftPan,BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(rightPan,BorderLayout.EAST);
}

public void initGamePan(){
    rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131869.jpg")));
    label1 = new JLabel("Nombre de mots trouvés : 0");
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label1.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,20));
    label1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));

    label2 = new JLabel("Score Actuel : 0 point");
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label2.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,20));
    label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));

    label3 = new JLabel(tWord.getStars());
    label3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label3.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,30));
    label3.setForeground(Color.blue);
    label3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,50));

    leftPan.add(label1);
    leftPan.add(label2);
    leftPan.add(label3);
    for(int i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
        Button[i]= new JButton(letters[i]);
        leftPan.add(Button[i]);
    }

    leftPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460,650));
    leftPan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    rightPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420,650));
    rightPan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

public void initListeners(){
    buttonListener= new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            clickedButton = ((JButton)(arg0.getSource())).getText().charAt(0); // on prend le bouton cliqué, on le convertis en string puis en char
            label3.setText(tWord.treatedWord(clickedButton));// on donne a la methode tretedWord de l'objet tWord le char clickedbutton pour faire le traitement sur le mot mystère
            ((JButton)(arg0.getSource())).setEnabled(false);

            if(tWord.isFound()==true){
                jop.showMessageDialog(null, "Bravo t'a trouvé le mot !", "U don't Say B|", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                motTrouvé = true;

            }
        }

    };
    for(int i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
        Button[i].addActionListener(buttonListener);
    }

}


public void setNewWord(){
    this.randWord = new Word();
    this.tWord = new TreatedWord(randWord.getRandWord());
    this.label3.setText(tWord.getStars());
}
public void resetButtons(){
    for(JButton B : this.Button){
        B.setEnabled(true);
    }
}


 public void addCustomListener(final CustomListener listener) {
        this.customListener.add(listener);
    }

 public void notifyWordFound(/* any data you could use */) {
        for(final CustomListener listener : this.customListener) {
            listener.wordFound(/* any data you could use */);
        }
    }
```

}

MyJFrame code:

public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

```
    private JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu file = new JMenu("Fichier");
    private JMenuItem neew = new JMenuItem("Nouveau");
    private JMenuItem score = new JMenuItem("Score");
    private JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quitter");
    private JMenu about = new JMenu("About");
    private JMenuItem how = new JMenuItem("Règles");
    private JMenuItem who = new JMenuItem("Credit");
    private int i=1;
    private ScorePanel scorepan = new ScorePanel(900,650);
    private ReglesJeuPanel rgpan = new ReglesJeuPanel(900,650);
    private GamePanel gamepan = new GamePanel();
    private JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("------------------------SAMAIKOM------------------------");
    private JTextArea texte = new JTextArea(    "Vous avez sept coups pour trouver le mot caché. Si vous réussissez, on recommence !\n" +
            "Plus vous trouvez de mots, plus votre score augmente. Alors, à vous de jouer !\n" +
            "Proverbe :\t« Pas vu, pas pris !\n" +
                "\tPris ! PENDU ! »");
public Fenetre(){
    this.setTitle("Le Pendu ...");
    this.setSize(900, 650);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    initMenu();
    initAcceuilPan();
    initListeners();
    this.setContentPane(container);
}

private void initMenu(){
    file.add(neew);
    file.add(score);
    file.addSeparator();
    file.add(quit);
    file.setMnemonic('F');
    neew.setMnemonic('N');
    neew.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    score.setMnemonic('S');
    score.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    quit.setMnemonic('Q');
    quit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));

    about.add(how);
    about.addSeparator();
    about.add(who);
    about.setMnemonic('A');
    how.setMnemonic('R');
    how.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    who.setMnemonic('C');
    who.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));

    menu.add(file);
    menu.add(about);
    this.setJMenuBar(menu);
}

private void initListeners(){
    score.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            container.removeAll();
            container.add(scorepan);
        }
    });
    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    how.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            container.removeAll();
            container.add(rgpan);
        }
    });
    neew.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            gamepan.setNewWord();
            gamepan.resetButtons();
            container.removeAll();
            container.add(gamepan);
        }
    });

    gamepan.addCustomListener(new CustomListener(){

        public void wordFound() {
        }

    });

    gamepan.notifyWordFound();       // where to put this ?????


}

private void initAcceuilPan(){
    pan.setBackground(Color.white);
    pan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131868.jpg")));
    texte.setEditable(false);
    Font F1 = new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,20);
    Font F2 = new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,15);
    label.setFont(F1);
    texte.setFont(F2);
    container.setBackground(Color.white);
    container.add(label);
    container.add(pan);
    container.add(texte);
    //container.add(gamepan);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fenetre F1 = new Fenetre();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some custom Event that can occur when a word is found:

```
public interface MyEventListener {
    public abstract void wordFound(/* any data you could use */);
}
```

Then make your `GamePan` capable of emitting such events:

```
public class GamePan extends JPanel {
    private final List<MyEventListener> myEventListeners = new LinkedList<>();

    // Here, keep everything you already have

    public void addMyEventListener(final MyEventListener listener) {
        this.myEventListeners.add(listener);
    }

    private void notifyWordFound(/* any data you could use */) {
        for(final MyEventListener listener : this.myEventListeners) {
            listener.wordFound(/* any data you could use */)
        }
    }
}
```

When the word is found, just call `GamePan#notifyWordFound`.
Then, register some updating method to be called in your `JFrame` when such an event occurs:

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
    // Here, keep everything you already have

    public JFrame() {
        // Here, keep everything you already have

        // Let's assume your ScorePanel instance is here:
        final ScorePanel scorePanel = new ScorePanel();

        this.gamePan.addMyEventListener(new MyEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void wordFound(/* any data you could use */) {
                // Update your application using any data you can use :)
                scorePanel.wordFound(/* any data you could use */);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here, we simply call the `ScorePanel#wordFound` method so the `ScorePanel` can be updated.

Don't forget that you can transmit any data you're interested in through all these methods. For example, if you want to transmit the word the user just found, the `MyEventListener#wordFound` method could be declared as follows:

```
public interface MyEventListener {
    public abstract void wordFound(final String word);
}
```

EDIT: Added some interaction with a `ScorePanel` instance to answer your additional question in comments :)

Comment: Thanx, I understand but where do I call gamepan.notifyWordFound ??? I mean where I put It in my JFrame ?? I Edited My post to add my code to make it simple

Comment: You need to notify that a word was found (i.e. use `notifyWordFound`) when... a word is found :)  
Basically, I think you'd like to use it where is test `if(tWord.isFound()==true)` (around line 90 in your file _GamePanel.java_, I believe. Just call it like this: `GamePanel.this.notifyWordFound();`.
By the way, `GamePan#notifyWordFound` should be `private` :)

Comment: And also, no need for `== true` in `if(tWord.isFound()==true)`, unless it's clearer in your opinion, if `tWord.isFound` is `true`, well it's `true`, and the condition to enter the `if` is verified, there is no need to explicitly compare it to `true` :)

Comment: One last thing, don't forget to accept the answer when you get your problem fixed and working, so future users will know that a solution has been found :)

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Just one more thing, why do I have to put `GamePanel.this.notifyWordFound()`  instead of `this.notifyWordFound()` (which doesn't work btw)

Comment: I have also another class scorepanel that needs to be informed that the word is found as well, I tought to add a gamepanel variable on it and addCustomListener to it, is it the sollution ? even if I won't really use the gamepanel ?

Comment: I just edited my answer to add some interaction with a ScorePanel instance :)

Comment: I also posted a new answer to reply to your other question about using `GamePanel.this.notifyWordFound()` instead of `this.notifyWordFound()`... Because there was kind of a lot to say!

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `ClassName.this` syntax is used inside of a nested class that is not `static`. It is used to access its outer class's instance. Let me give you an example:

```
class OuterClass {
    private final String text = "I'm the outer class!";

    class NestedClass {
        private final String text = "I'm the nested class!";

        public final String getText() {
            return this.text;  // "I'm the outer class!"
        }

        public final String getOuterClassText() {
            return OuterClass.this.text;  // "I'm the nested class!"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your case, the nested class you have is actually an **anonymous class** you created by *instantiating the `MyEventListener` interface*, with the following code:

```
gamePanel.addMyEventListener(new MyEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void wordFound(/* any data you could use */) {
        // Here, access your GamePanel's instance attributes and methods using GamePanel.this
    }
});
```

---

Let me explain to you what the above code exactly did:

```
new MyEventListener() {
}
```

This notation will create an anonymous class that `implements MyEventListener`. You can modify that class definition by putting anything you want between the brackets `{}`. Since you implement some interface, you have to `override` every `abstract method` declared in that interface, like this:

```
new MyEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void wordFound(/* any data you could use */) {
    }
}
```

I hope it's clear and it helped you :)

Comment: This answer does not reply directly to the question asked, it's actually intended to give additional information as requested in comments of my above answer.